# Impossible deduced upper bounds in AMPL

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, ampl

I'm intending to conduct an optimization where I want to maximize the amount of flow in a system subjected to some time constraints and some "these routes must be fulfilled" constraints. The first time constraint states that each vehicle must not exceed a 24 hour workload (expressed in minutes). The second time constraint is a subtour elimination constraint which also states that the starttime at the "visiting" node cannot be activated before the vehicle has had time to travel etc. Constraint3 describes that the road between K1 and N1 must be used no more than 9 times, using whichever vehicle k. The last constraint states that all the vehicles from the specific nodes must return at the end of the day.

```
 maximize maxamount: sum{i in V, j in V, k in K} x[i,j,k];

 subject to TimeConstraint {k in K}: 
     sum{i in V, j in V} traveltime[i,j]*x[i,j,k] <= 1440; 

 subject to StartTime{i in V,j in V, k in K}:
     starttime[i] + servicetime[i] +traveltime[i,j] - 1300 * (1 - x[i,j,k]) <= starttime[j];

 subject to Constraint3:
     sum{k in K} x["K1","N1",k] <= 9;

 subject to EndNode{k in K}: 
     sum{i in V}x[i,"K1",k] - sum{j in V} x["K1",j,k]= 0;
```

Constraint3 and EndNode has several more constraints of the same type (just with other "predefined locations", such as for instance the road between K1 and N2 cannot exceed 4 visits and so on).

My problem is that I get the error Impossible deduced bounds x[K1,K1,1] has lower bound = 0 and upper bound = -76 which I've understood stems from conflicting constraints. My question is however: how? Using almost exclusively binary variables, I cannot see why the code above is not working. Have I misunderstood what I'm actually doing in my model?

I've noticed that the compiler only complains when i=j, so I checked my .dat file and noticed that the traveltime between i and j, when i=j were very big (so the program would not choose those routes). However, editing that .dat file to no longer exceed TimeConstraints limit automatically still gives me the same error (albeitly lesser, now the upper bound is -1 instead of -76).

I hope someone could shed some light into this

Thanks in advance
Cenderze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the traveltime between i and j, when i=j were very big (so the program would not choose those routes)

If `traveltime[i,j]` = `M` (very big) then `StartTime` for `i=j` reads

```
servicetime[i] + M - 1300 * (1 - x[i,j,k]) <= 0     <=>
1300 * x[i,j,k] <= 1300 - servicetime[i] - M
```

Therefore, whenever `M > 1300 - servicetime[i]`, the problem is infeasible.

I would suggest defining the `X` variables for all pairs `(i,j)` with `i<>j`, or (if the problem is symmetric) with `i < j`.

**Follow up from the comment**

The following snippet works well when plugged in the [AMPL Online Editor](http://ampl.com/try-ampl/try-ampl-online/):

```
param n := 10;
set N:= 1..n;
set V := {i in N, j in N: i <> j};
display V;
```

Output:

```
set V :=
(1,2)    (2,3)    (3,4)    (4,5)    (5,6)    (6,7)    (7,8)    (8,9)    (9,10)
(1,3)    (2,4)    (3,5)    (4,6)    (5,7)    (6,8)    (7,9)    (8,10)   (10,1)
(1,4)    (2,5)    (3,6)    (4,7)    (5,8)    (6,9)    (7,10)   (9,1)    (10,2)
(1,5)    (2,6)    (3,7)    (4,8)    (5,9)    (6,10)   (8,1)    (9,2)    (10,3)
(1,6)    (2,7)    (3,8)    (4,9)    (5,10)   (7,1)    (8,2)    (9,3)    (10,4)
(1,7)    (2,8)    (3,9)    (4,10)   (6,1)    (7,2)    (8,3)    (9,4)    (10,5)
(1,8)    (2,9)    (3,10)   (5,1)    (6,2)    (7,3)    (8,4)    (9,5)    (10,6)
(1,9)    (2,10)   (4,1)    (5,2)    (6,3)    (7,4)    (8,5)    (9,6)    (10,7)
(1,10)   (3,1)    (4,2)    (5,3)    (6,4)    (7,5)    (8,6)    (9,7)    (10,8)
(2,1)    (3,2)    (4,3)    (5,4)    (6,5)    (7,6)    (8,7)    (9,8)    (10,9);
== 1 ==========================
```

Change your snippet to

```
set N = {'K1', 'K2','K3','K4'};
set V := {i in N, j in N: i != j};
display V
```

and give it a go. I get:

```
set V :=
(K1,K2)   (K1,K4)   (K2,K3)   (K3,K1)   (K3,K4)   (K4,K2)
(K1,K3)   (K2,K1)   (K2,K4)   (K3,K2)   (K4,K1)   (K4,K3);
== 1 ==========================
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your input!  

I've been searching for how to define X to avoid using i=j, using the example at [link](http://myweb.clemson.edu/~pbelott/bulk/teaching/mthsc440/flows+networks.pdf) where it says that one can write
set V := 1..n;
set A within {i in V, j in V: i != j};

However this gives an error (regarding the "{"). Do you know if one can obtain the desired in another matter?

Comment: Have you declared 'n' as a parameter? What happens if you change 'within' with '='?

Comment: Using both 
set N := 'K1', 'K2','K3','K4';
set V := {i in N, j in N: i != j};
and set V = {i in N, j in N: i != j};
produces the same error, which is that the compiler is not fund of having the { where it is. Strange as I see no difference from that code from the one provided in the link earlier.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Unfortunately it did not work, even when using a bunch of different combinations of ":=" and ":" and "=" before the set. Very strange, even when copying your snippet off the bat I receive the same error. Shouldn't be because of some update neither when we use the same online editor. The only thing I'm using besides the online editor is Notepad++.

Comment: I can recall back in the day I was using AMPL regularly that there were a few obscure error messages.. Just to make it clearer, I went on [this page](http://ampl.com/cgi-bin/ampl/amplcgi), pasted your snippet on the bottom window and received the output on the window above when I pressed "send". I can probably help more with debugging, can you post some more code? This takes another path from the original question, but feel free to update it and extend it (or maybe post a new question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I've managed to remodel so I wouldn't need to induce another set removing the i = j possibility. Accepted your answer as it helped me greatly in terms of how to remove my impossible bounds.